# Getting Marionette/Geckodriver up and running with Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-marionette, geckodriver

So I've been having an issue getting my Protractor/Jasmine tests running in FireFox.  I've been aware of the version issue from FireFox that doesn't support selenium angular/bootstrap etc etc and that has been my issue to date.

I was informed to try geckodriver but really can't find any good resources on how to set it up using protractor and jasmine.  Or even which driver is the appropriate one to use.

Recently I've tried the following to get FF back up and running (all resulted with no luck):

- Downgraded FireFox to as low as 33.x.x while keeping
  Protractor/Jasmine at current versions (4.0.5 and 2.51 respectively).
- Downgraded Protractor to as low as 3.0.0 while keeping FF at current version (47.0.1)
- Downgraded both Protractor and FF to the lowest above versions.
- Used Latest Version of FF 47.0.1 with lesser versions of Protractor.
- Used Latest Version of FF 47.0.1 with latest version of Protractor 4.0.5
- Used directConnect: true and directConnet: false

So I guess now I have one of two questions:
1. Could somebody post a protractor config snippet using the geckodriver / or direct me to a walk-through of this.
2. Inform me of a work around or a working solution (versions of both webdrivers/protractor/jasmine, etc).

If you need to see errors or my config file or anything at all please just simply comment and I'll be happy to revise.

Comment: I just tried getting FF to run... sadly, there seems to be a lot of misinformation out there on this topic. Like you I tried a lot of it and nothing worked. [Protractor browser support](http://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support) currently says _(*) WebDriver support fr [sic] Firefox has changed recently, and FireFox version 48 does not work properly with the current tools. For the moment, we recommend testing against FireFox 47._

This is sadness, as it should be _easily_ addressed by one of the teams... but alas, is not.

Answer (score 1):

There was a period of time around Firefox v46 and Selenium v2.5x where things were incompatible due to changes to the firefox web-driver. The issues were quickly addressed by the community.

The issue with Protractor lies with the webdriver-manager being a bit out of date with the updates. As per discussions on github, they are aware of this, and a fix is coming.

The workaround in the meantime is to manually update the outdated pieces.

Here's how you'd do it, run

```
webdriver-manager update
```

This will give you the paths to all the components the webdriver-manager handles for you.

Navigate to the selenium-server-standalone.jar file (protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar in my case) and replace this with the latest selenium standalone jar (anything v3+ should be good). Make sure to retain the exact filename as the previous jar file. (link: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Repeat the process to get the latest Gecko web-driver. Uncompress and replace the current version. (link: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Now run your tests through protractor and you should be good with the latest version of Firefox.

Good luck and happy testing :)